# compare type time in a SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I created a scalar-valued function that has the following (***part***) of code in it:

```
declare @start_time22 time(7);
select @start_time22=Courses.[Course start time] from Courses where [Course ID]=@val1 and [Course days]='monday wednesday';

if(@start_time22 is not null)
    begin
        IF (@start_time not between @start_time22 and @end_time22)
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 0
            END
        IF (@end_time not between @start_time22 and @end_time22)
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = 0
            END
    end
else 
    begin
        set @Result = 5
    end


RETURN @Result
```

The function always return the value "**5**" , so i was wondering if i can compare type time in the first place...
or is there something wrong with my code???

Comment: `[Course days]='monday wednesday'` looks fishy

Comment: @Andomar checked that... not the problem!!

Comment: where have you declare @endtime22?

Comment: @Prahalad declared but not shown in the above code, the function returns always 5 , and thats the problem..

Comment: Can you show me How do you pass the value to the function ?
What is the value in Courses.[Course start time]? it is like 1234567?

Comment: Then what is the value this variable (@endtime22) has?

Comment: this means, from table value is not populated to 'start_time22'. that is 'start_time22' value is always null and so you are getting 5

Comment: @mari its a NOT NULL column...

Comment: yeah @HammamMuhareb. Did you try printing 'start_time22'variable inside your block. Can you tell what it returns? So that we can come to a conclusion whether it's getting data from table.

Comment: Then `where [Course ID]=@val1 and [Course days]='monday wednesday';` must be reducing the result set to 0 rows. We don't have your data or table definitions, so we're not able to debug further. But it's obvious from inspection that, if this part is setting the result to 5, it can only be because `@start_time22` is always `null`. Could `@val1` be `null` from a previous part?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no `@val1` cannot be null

Comment: As Mari said, the only way your result will be 5 is if `@start_time22` is `null`. If the column in the table is defined as `NOT NULL`, then, as Damien said, the query which sets the `@start_time22` variable is not returning any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want the query to be:

```
select @start_time22=Courses.[Course start time]
from Courses
where [Course ID]=@val1 and [Course days] in ('monday', 'wednesday');
```

As the comments basically explain, when you declare a variable then the value is set to NULL.  If you want to set it to another value, you can using syntax such as:

```
declare @str varchar(255) = 'My favorite string'
```

Because the query returns no results, the variable never gets assigned a value.  It remains as a NULL value.

Also, you can do the work in the query itself, using `case` logic in the `select` rather than using a variable and then doing `if` logic:

```
select @result = (case when <whatever . . . )
from Courses
where [Course ID]=@val1 and [Course days] in ('monday', 'wednesday');
```

Comment: I teseted the select statement and it returns a time value like it should, but only in specific cases.. that's why i used the `@start_time22 is not null` in the if statement,,, the thing is that it always goes to the else and returns a `5` as the result!!!!!!

Comment: Default the value to 5 when you define the variable . . . `set @Result = 5; <the query here>`.  If the query does not set the value, it remains at 5.